# How to count the factors in ordered sequence

Tags: r, count, sequence, strsplit

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
userID Score  Task_Alpha Task_Beta Task_Charlie Task_Delta 
3108  -8.00   Easy       Easy      Easy         Easy    
3207   3.00   Hard       Easy      Match        Match
3350   5.78   Hard       Easy      Hard         Hard
3961   10.00  Easy       NA        Hard         Hard
4021   10.00  Easy       Easy      NA           Hard


1. userID is factor variable
2. Score is numeric
3. All the 'Task_' features are factor variables with possible values 'Hard', 'Easy', 'Match' or NA
```

I want to count the  possible transitions between the `Task_` features. For reference, the possible transitions are:

```
EE transition from Easy -> Easy
EM transition from Easy -> Match
EH transition from Easy -> Hard
ME transition from Match-> Easy
MM transition from Match-> Match
MH transition from Match-> Hard
HE transition from Hard -> Easy
HM transition from Hard -> Match
HH transition from Hard -> Hard
```

Since there are three possible values (excluding the NA case), the output columns would be as below:

```
userID  EE  EM  EH  MM  ME  MH  HH  HE  HM
3108    3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3207    0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
3350    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
3961    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
4021    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

1) In this example each userID can have at most 3 state transitions.

2) Note that for users 3961 and 4021, NA has reduced the possible state transitions.

Any advice on these questions would be greatly appreciated.

The data `dput()` is :

```
df <- structure(list(
userID = c(3108L, 3207L, 3350L, 3961L, 4021L), 
Score = c(-8, 3, 5.78, 10, 10), 
Task_Alpha = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard"), class = "factor"), 
Task_Beta = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = "Easy", class = "factor"), 
Task_Charlie = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Match"), class = "factor"), 
Task_Delta = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Match"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another idea via base R can be to paste the values to their previous value (rowwise), convert to factor to get **all 9 levels** (using `expand.grid` with only the levels you want - which also takes care of NAs), and finally count the values via `table`. The last step is to bind the IDs with the results, i.e.

```
cbind.data.frame(df$userID, t(apply(df[-c(1:2)], 1, function(i) { 
                          i1 <- paste(i[-length(i)], i[-1]); 
                          i1 <- factor(i1, levels = do.call(paste, expand.grid(c('Easy', 'Match', 'Hard'), 
                                                                             c('Easy', 'Match', 'Hard')))); 
                         table(i1) })))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   df$userID Easy Easy Match Easy Hard Easy Easy Match Match Match Hard Match Easy Hard Match Hard Hard Hard
> 1      3108         3          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         0
> 2      3207         0          0         1          1           1          0         0          0         0
> 3      3350         0          0         1          0           0          0         1          0         1
> 4      3961         0          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         1
> 5      4021         1          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         0
> ```

Comment: Sotos, Thanks for posting a solution. I tried your script, the code keeps running forever. Did it happen on your side too?

Answer (score 2):

Another option similar to Sotos' approach but 1) using `data.table`, 2) not using `factor` and 3) replacing `table` with `Rfast::rowTabulate`:

```
v <- c('Hard', 'Match', 'Easy')
vv <- do.call(paste, expand.grid(v, v))
DT[, (vv) := {
        mat <- mapply(paste, .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with=FALSE], .SD[, -1L])
        as.data.table(Rfast::rowTabulate(matrix(match(mat, vv, 0L), nrow=.N)))
    }, .SDcols=Task_Alpha:Task_Delta]
```

output:

```
   userID Score Task_Alpha Task_Beta Task_Charlie Task_Delta Hard Hard Match Hard Easy Hard Hard Match Match Match Easy Match Hard Easy Match Easy Easy Easy
1:   3108 -8.00       Easy      Easy         Easy       Easy         0          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         3
2:   3207  3.00       Hard      Easy        Match      Match         0          0         0          0           1          1         1          0         0
3:   3350  5.78       Hard      Easy         Hard       Hard         1          0         1          0           0          0         1          0         0
4:   3961 10.00       Easy      <NA>         Hard       Hard         1          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         0
5:   4021 10.00       Easy      Easy         <NA>       Hard         0          0         0          0           0          0         0          0         1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
library(Rfast)
DT <- structure(list(
    userID = c(3108L, 3207L, 3350L, 3961L, 4021L), 
    Score = c(-8, 3, 5.78, 10, 10), 
    Task_Alpha = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard"), class = "factor"), 
    Task_Beta = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L), .Label = "Easy", class = "factor"), 
    Task_Charlie = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Match"), class = "factor"), 
    Task_Delta = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Easy", "Hard", "Match"), class = "factor")), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
setDT(DT)
```

Would be interesting to know how fast this approach works on actual dataset and if actual dataset is large.

---

edit: added some timings

```
library(data.table)
nr <- 1e6
vec <- c('Hard', 'Match', 'Easy', NA)
DT <- data.table(userID=1:nr, Task_Alpha=sample(vec, nr, TRUE), Task_Beta=sample(vec, nr, TRUE),
    Task_Charlie=sample(vec, nr, TRUE), Task_Delta=sample(vec, nr, TRUE))
df <- as.data.frame(DT)
DT0 <- copy(DT)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)

mtd0 <- function() {
    t(apply(df[-1L], 1, function(i) {
        i1 <- paste(i[-length(i)], i[-1L]);
        i1 <- factor(i1, levels = do.call(paste, expand.grid(c('Easy', 'Match', 'Hard'),
            c('Easy', 'Match', 'Hard'))));
        table(i1)
    }))
}

mtd1 <- function() {
    f_cols <- names(DT0)[ sapply( DT0, is.factor ) ]
    DT0[, (f_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = f_cols ]
    #melt to long format
    DT.melt <- melt( DT0, id.vars = "userID", measure.vars = patterns( task = "^Task_"))
    #set order of Aplha-Beta-etc...
    DT.melt[ grepl( "Alpha",   variable ), order := 1 ]
    DT.melt[ grepl( "Beta",    variable ), order := 2 ]
    DT.melt[ grepl( "Charlie", variable ), order := 3 ]
    DT.melt[ grepl( "Delta",   variable ), order := 4 ]
    #order DT.melt
    setorder( DT.melt, userID, order )
    #fill in codes EE, etc...
    DT.melt[, `:=`( code1 = gsub( "(^.).*", "\\1", value ),
        code2 = gsub( "(^.).*", "\\1", shift( value, type = "lead" ) ) ),
        by = userID ]
    #filter only rows without NA
    DT.melt <- DT.melt[ complete.cases( DT.melt ) ]
    #cast to wide output
    dcast( DT.melt, userID ~ paste0( code2, code1 ), fun.aggregate = length )
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    v <- c('Hard', 'Match', 'Easy')
    vv <- do.call(paste, expand.grid(v, v))
    DT2[, (vv) := {
        mat <- mapply(paste, .SD[, -ncol(.SD), with=FALSE], .SD[, -1L])
        as.data.table(Rfast::rowTabulate(matrix(match(mat, vv, 0L), nrow=.N)))
    }, .SDcols=Task_Alpha:Task_Delta]
}

bench::mark(mtd0(), mtd1(), mtd2(), check=FALSE)
```

timings:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 13
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                     memory                 time     gc              
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                     <list>                 <list>   <list>          
1 mtd0()        2.19m    2.19m   0.00760     252MB    2.26      1   297      2.19m <int[,9] [1,000,000 x 9]>  <df[,3] [171,481 x 3]> <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
2 mtd1()       33.16s   33.16s   0.0302      856MB    0.754     1    25     33.16s <df[,10] [843,688 x 10]>   <df[,3] [8,454 x 3]>   <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
3 mtd2()     844.95ms 844.95ms   1.18        298MB    1.18      1     1   844.95ms <df[,14] [1,000,000 x 14]> <df[,3] [8,912 x 3]>   <bch:tm> <tibble [1 x 3]>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution, I tried the first script, however I get the following error:

      "Error in `:=`((vv), { : 
       Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for 
       use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=")."

Any advice how to deal with this?

Comment: You need to make sure your variable is a data.table. You can use setDT to concert it from data.frame to data.table

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
#set df to data.table
setDT(df)
#convert factor-columns to character
f_cols <- names(df)[ sapply( df, is.factor ) ]
df[, (f_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = f_cols ]
#melt to long format
DT.melt <- melt( df, id.vars = "userID", measure.vars = patterns( task = "^Task_"), variable.name = grep("^Task",names(df), value = TRUE) )
#set order of Aplha-Beta-etc...
DT.melt[ grepl( "Alpha",   variable ), order := 1 ]
DT.melt[ grepl( "Beta",    variable ), order := 2 ]
DT.melt[ grepl( "Charlie", variable ), order := 3 ]
DT.melt[ grepl( "Delta",   variable ), order := 4 ]
#order DT.melt
setorder( DT.melt, userID, order )
#fill in codes EE, etc...
DT.melt[, `:=`( code1 = gsub( "(^.).*", "\\1", value ),
                code2 = gsub( "(^.).*", "\\1", shift( value, type = "lead" ) ) ),
        by = userID ]
#filter only rows without NA
DT.melt <- DT.melt[ complete.cases( DT.melt ) ]
str(DT.melt)
#cast to wide output
dcast( DT.melt, userID ~ paste0( code2, code1 ), fun.aggregate = length )

#    userID EE EH EM HE HH MM
# 1:   3108  3  0  0  0  0  0
# 2:   3207  0  0  1  1  0  1
# 3:   3350  0  1  0  1  1  0
# 4:   3961  0  0  0  0  1  0
# 5:   4021  1  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: updated the answer to deal with the `factor`-columns in your data...

Comment: 2nd update: whoops, I had to switch `paste0( code1, code2 )` in the last row to `paste0( code2, code1 )`... now it matches your output (except missing combinations like `ME`.